# I want something like this : Search button in actionbar

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I want to make the Search view like the flowing picture.

i use this code. But did't get the result i expected .

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48px"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

[image]

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `Toolbar` instead `Actionbar`,try this way

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/theme_primary" />

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Check this for more https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

Answer (score 0):

**menu_main.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

**\res\xml\searchable.xml:**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.searchview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Log.i("onQueryTextChange", newText);

                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Log.i("onQueryTextSubmit", query);

                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```